# PHP -convert json array with dotted key to $this->data in cakephp controller

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp

I have a json array in my Particles controller that looks like this after json_encode, true:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Particle.day_id] => Sat
            [Particle.week_no] => 1
            [Particle.pattern_id] => 589
            [Particle.work] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Particle.day_id] => Fri
            [Particle.week_no] => 1
            [Particle.pattern_id] => 589
            [Particle.work] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Particle.day_id] => Thu
            [Particle.week_no] => 1
            [Particle.pattern_id] => 589
            [Particle.work] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (.....
```

I am trying to convert this array to the correct format for a multiple record save:

```
Array
(
    [Particle] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                            [day_id] => Sat
                            [week_no] => 1
                            [pattern_id] => 589
                            [work] => 0
                        )
            [1] => Array
                (
                            [day_id] => Fri
                            [week_no] => 1
                            [pattern_id] => 589
                            [work] => 0
                        )
                )


                 ....
```

Where Particle is my Cakephp model name.

The nearest I can get is using this code (php):

```
 $output = array();

        foreach ($jsonData as $keyA => $valueA) {
        foreach ($valueA as $keyB => $valueB) {
            $output = Set::insert( $output, $keyB, $valueB );
        }
        }
```

Where $jsonData is the json_encoded array.
This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [Particle] => Array
        (
            [day_id] => Sun
            [week_no] => 1
            [pattern_id] => 589
            [work] => 1
        )

)
```

Which is only the first part of the array - how do I get the rest of the array?

I know the answer will probably be straighforward but it has baffled me for too long now!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
$parentKey = null;
foreach ($jsonData as $keyA => $valueA) {
     foreach ($valueA as $keyB => $valueB) {
        $keyB = explode('.', $keyB);
        list($parentKey, $childKey) = $keyB;
        $output[$childKey] = $valueB;
     }

    if(!isset($result[$parentKey]))
       $result[$parentKey] = array();

   array_push($result[$parentKey], $output);
}


 print_r($result);
```

Your current code it over writing the array $output. Thats why it is showing you the last part of data.

Comment: Now I see! This brings me to my next issue - the $result array does not quite match the format I need (as shown in the original question).

Comment: Not too sure how to change this - I have tried a few combinations of keys and values but can't seem to hit the right combination - do you have any clues?

Comment: I think there is a syntax error on the list($parent.. line, not too sure what it is.

Comment: This works a treat! Thanks for your quick answer - now I can move on to my next problem!